# ksh remote function calling another remote function2

Tags: shell, unix, syntax, ksh

I am having problem to run simple code below:

```
#!/bin/ksh
set -x 

function test_me
{
set -x
date
}

function check_me 
{
set -x
ssh ${HST2} "$(typeset -f test_me); test_me"
}

ssh ${HST1} "$(typeset -f); check_me"
```

Fails with syntax error at line 5: `;;' unexpected

Answer (score 0):

Though I can't explain why this gives you the particular error message you see, at least I see that your code can't work:

First you run in one process (on HST1) the commands

```
function check_me 
{
  set -x
  ssh ${HST2} "$(typeset -f test_me); test_me"
};check_me
```

On HST1 defines only the function check_me, nothing else. Then you run this `check_me`.

Inside this function, you refer to two things: A variable HST2, and a function `test_me`. There is nothing in your code which would define these entities. They are only defined in that initial process, where you do the SSH, but they are not defined on the remote process on the host $HST1.

Moreover, you don't even run a ksh on $HST1. At least I don't see and ksh invocation in your code. Actually, you just pass a `function ....` to $HST1, and `function` is not an executable.

Comment: from sath I am logging on Oracle RAC cluster.. I login on first node of RAC1A, then prepare list of database on this RAC1, on various node RAC1B, RAC1C, RAC1D... then login on each of RAC1B and connect to DB...  $HST1 and $HST2 is just to hide the hostname, you can put anything  you like .... SATH ==> RAC1A ===> RAC1B  ... where HST1 is RAC1A and HST2 is RAC1B

Comment: IF you have any 3 paired server where ssh keys is rolled out in SATH ==> RAC1A ===> RAC1B, you can test above code .. SATH ==> HST1 ===> HST2

Comment: #!/bin/ksh
set -x 

function test_me
{
set -x
date
}

function check_me 
{
set -x
ssh hostname2 "$(typeset -f test_me); test_me"
}

ssh hostname1 "$(typeset -f); check_me"

Comment: can you check below code,  I havent got answer yet. `#!/bin/ksh
set -x 

function test_me
{
set -x
date
}

function check_me 
{
set -x
ssh ${HST2} "$(typeset -f test_me); test_me"
}

ssh ${HST1} "$(typeset -f); check_me"`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/ksh
set -x 

function second_me
{
set -x
date
}

function first_me 
{
set -x
ssh hostname2 "$(typeset -f second_me); second_me"
}

#from local_machine
ssh hostname1 "$(typeset -f); first_me"
```

above  Fails with syntax error at line X: `;;' unexpected

But If I add extra dummy function third_me, things work fine, looks like ksh bug?

```
#!/bin/ksh
set -x 


function third_me
{
set -x
date
}

function second_me
{
set -x
date
}

function first_me 
{
set -x
ssh hostname2 "$(typeset -f second_me); second_me"
}

#from local_machine
ssh hostname1 "$(typeset -f); first_me"
```

Code works fine

Comment: You did not indicate, which one is line X. Furthermore, you have added plenty of `set -x`, but don't show the output of this trace.

Answer (score 0):

Another work around using sub-function:

```
#!/bin/ksh
set -x 

function first_me 
{
set -x
    function second_me
    {
    set -x
    date
    }
ssh hostname2 "$(typeset -f second_me); second_me"
}

#from local_machine
ssh hostname1 "$(typeset -f); first_me"
```